# scratch countries effect of map using react native or flutter

Tags: react-native, flutter, expo

[image]
I want to implement something like visited countries in react native or maybe flutter, using google map I don't know if is possible to make some animations like scratch a country from silver default map like in image from above.

I think to implement some animation above to a static map, but maybe is there something already implemented, I don't find something similar on expo or in flutter,...
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can reference https://github.com/gi097/flutter_clickable_regions

This is a simple application which displays an `SVG image` with `clickable regions`. It displays all the provinces from The `Netherlands`. When you click on it, it will highlight the clicked province.

After download this package, execute command `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

```
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 513ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 52ms

[INFO] Succeeded after 13.6s with 1 outputs (5 actions)
```

working demo

[image]

code snippet

```
Widget _buildProvince(Province province) {
    return ClipPath(
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          CustomPaint(painter: PathPainter(province)),
          Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _provincePressed(province),
                  child: Container(
                      color: _pressedProvince == province
                          ? Color(0xFF7C7C7C)
                          : Colors.transparent)))
        ]),
        clipper: PathClipper(province));
  }
```